# I cannot install new packages: "Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock"

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, apt, dpkg

I tried to install jdk/jre:

```
ben@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

However, I got this message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I cannot get git to install either, so I don't think it is a problem with the specific package I selected. What that error means, and how to deal with it?

Comment: Have you tried just rebooting? An error like that usually indicates that another package manager has locked the whole system. If you reboot, it should not persist.

Comment: @Ben7005 I'd hold off on the rebooting and wait for your downloads to finish

Comment: 3 years ago there was also [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/how-do-i-fix-a-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-problem) on askubuntu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have the GUI package manager/or update manager programs running? If so there's a conflict, simply close those programs down and your command line should work.

Comment: I am downloading some software from the software center... I'll finish that and see if it works.

Comment: @Ben7005 That's most likely it .. in fact trying to use both of those GUI programs at the same time will result in the same error message, so I'd not be surprised you'd get this with the command line while something else is going on.

Comment: That's *definitely* it. Only one of `aptitude`, `apt-get`, `dpkg` and the software centre can install at the same time. They use a lock on `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` to ensure that, hence the error message.

Comment: Either that or one of the above frontends was /very/ rudely interrupted mid-install and its `dpkg` backend was still hanging on to the lock. Can sometimes happen running `aptitude` remotely and losing connection while `dpkg` was waiting for user input (eg, to tell it what to do with a modified config file)

Comment: check if the lockfile exists, and if there is no dpkg/apt process running, delete it.

Comment: @Ben7005 So, what happened? Did you resolve the problem? Just curious :)

Comment: Yes, you had the right solution. I was just being stupid.

Comment: @Ben7005 Glad it worked out. FWIW, I don't think you were being stupid, you just came up against a limitation of the system.

Answer (score 1):

This should be used as last resource. If you use this carelessly you can end with a broken system. Please evaluate other answers first before trying this.
You can delete the lock file with the following command:

`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

After that, try installing again.

Comment: It works on all linus distributions. Try removing it and install.

Comment: It works on all distributions that use `apt`, not all Linuxes. It is also a pretty bad idea, as you point out, the OP should first look for running `apt` processes and kill them.

Comment: Yup @terdon I mentioned in first line that it should be done when no other solutions helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1) Open a terminal

2) sudo dpkg --configure -a