# cannot install in linux mint rebecca

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I have a problem to install new packages/software in linux mint rebecca.

My OS:

```
> userubuntu@Oracle ~ $ uname -a 
  Linux Oracle 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:30:01 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux 
> userubuntu@Oracle ~ $ lsb_release -a 
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID:   LinuxMint 
  Description:  Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca
  Release:  17.1 
  Codename: rebecca
```

When I run command, for example, `sudo apt-get install filezilla`, the result is

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  filezilla-common libtinyxml2.6.2 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  filezilla filezilla-common libtinyxml2.6.2 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 583 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7.483 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23,5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I already run command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

but nothing changed.

I ran command `sudo dpkg --configure --pending` and result is

```
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                   
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
```

EDIT: in file install-info.postinst,

```
umask 022

# we only have to call update-info-dir for configure, reconfigure, and
# triggered transitions. All others are simply ignored.

case $1 in
    configure|reconfigure|triggered)
        update-info-dir
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```

UPDATE 2016/10/07

I ran command `df /var/lib/dpkg/` and `df -i /var/lib/dpkg/` and result is

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       12655760 6335500   5708212  53% /

Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      819200 235995 583205   29% /
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I cannot install new packages: "Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41708/i-cannot-install-new-packages-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock)

Comment: I already follow the answers of this question but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please add output of `df /var/lib/dpkg` and `df -i /var/lib/dpkg` to your question. I wonder if you've run out of disk resources and therefore cannot create the lock file. You can test this with `sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/testfile` and clean up afterwards with `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/testfile`.

Comment: Checking out [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process/15436#15436) might help you